# Element of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $1\leq p \leq \infty$. Is there an easy way to argue that $e^{-\vert x\vert ^2}$ is an element of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (integral w.r.t. $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure)?

Answer (score 3):

$$\int e^{-|x|^2}=\int\prod_{i=1}^de^{-x_i^2}=\prod_{i=1}^d\int e^{-x_i^2},$$
and $x_i\longmapsto e^{-x_i^2}$ is $L^p$ for all $i$

Comment: thanks! But ok, why is $x_i\longmapsto e^{-x_i^2}$ in $L^p$ for all $i$?

Comment: it's a famous result. But to argue, $e^{-x^2}\leq \frac{1}{x^2}$, and thus, $$\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-x^2}dx=2\int_{1}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx+\int_0^1e^{-x^2}dx\leq 2\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx+\int_0^1e^{-x^2}dx\leq ...$$

Comment: @tubmaster It's the Fubini theorem.